# How i use UISearchController in UICollectionViewController using Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

I want to implement UISearchController in UICollectionViewController. But i don't want to implement search in CollectionView I need SearchController in Swift.

I need to show Search Controller on Search Click

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) { } 
func searchBarResultsListButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) { }
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
  self.view.addSubview(searchController.view) 
}
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) { }
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {}
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) { }
```

I am adding when search is active but not showing

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

[image]

Please suggest me if any one have any idea .

Comment: show us some of your code or your flow

Comment: I need to show Search Controller on Search Click
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        
    }
    func searchBarResultsListButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   
    }
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
     
        self.view.addSubview(searchController.view)
    }
    
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    }
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
  {}
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    }

Comment: func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
     
        self.view.addSubview(searchController.view)
    }
    I am adding when search is active but not showing
 let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

Comment: Anuj, edit your own question and put the code you already tried to solve your problem. Show also what it's not working and what is was expect to do. This way is easier to help you.

Comment: don't put code in here. update you question. and also add methods of collectionview delegate and datasource